# ¿Como hacer una expresion de cargo abono y saldo en un reportviewer?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, reportviewer

Hola en mi tabla SQL tengo los campos CARGO y ABONO y muestro esos registros en un reportviewer, y quiero agregar una columna llamada SALDO para que me muestre el salgo. Asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aclaro que la columna Saldo no existe en mi tabla de base de datos, esa columna la tengo que agregar en el reportviewer, pero nose como sacar la fomular, ademas de que son muchos registros. Este que pongo aqui es de ejemplo.
Gracias por leer

Comment: Tienes algun error en la consola?

Comment: Puedes hacer una funcion en de tipo expresión usando Runing Value, deberias visitar este [link](https://translate.google.com.mx/translate?hl=es&sl=en&u=https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-runningvalue-function&prev=search)